# How to change the forecolor and backcolor of a label based on input into a textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, label, back

I have a windows form application. Based on a users age(inputting), I want to highlight one of the following labels "child, preteen, teen, adult" based on what they enter for age. I currently have a textbox for age that submits the users age to a label further down the form.

Here is what I am using:
txtAge
lblChild (<12)
lblPreTeen(13 to 15)
lblTeen(16 to 18)
lblAdult(18>)
btnSubmit

Thanks. I am new to coding and still grasping the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend changing your TextBox to a [NumericUpDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (called numAge), if possible.  Go to the properties of the NumericUpDown in the Form editor and click the Events button (lightning bolt).  If you double-click the [ValueChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.valuechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) option, it will create the stub for the following method:

```
private void numAge_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (numAge.Value > 0 && numAge.Value < 13)
        {
            // Child
            // Highlight label
        }
        else if (numAge.Value > 12 && numAge.Value < 16)
        {
            // Pre-Teen
            // Highlight label
        }
        else if (numAge.Value > 15 && numAge.Value < 19)
        {
            // Teen
            // Highlight label
        }
        else if (numAge.Value > 18)
        {
            // Adult
            // Highlight label
        }
        else
        {
            // Clear the highlights
        }
    }
```

If you must use a TextBox, use the [TextChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) method.  That way you don't need the Submit Button:

```
private void txtAge_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int txtAgeValue = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAge.Text))
        {
            txtAgeValue = int.Parse(txtAge.Text);
        }
        if (txtAgeValue > 0 && txtAgeValue < 13)
        {
            // Child
            // Highlight label
        }
        else if (txtAgeValue > 12 && txtAgeValue < 16)
        {
            // Pre-Teen
            // Highlight label
        }
        else if (txtAgeValue > 15 && txtAgeValue < 19)
        {
            // Teen
            // Highlight label
        }
        else if (numAge.Value > 18)
        {
            // Adult
            // Highlight label
        }
        else
        {
            // Clear the highlights
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

on the text box enter event you can update relevant label colors with a few if statements.